# Weird behaviour of bash in Kali Terminal (Qt I think) - piping to nc ends with awaiting input forever

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, pipe, qt, nc

I've been trying to pipe bytecode to netcat (`nc`) like this:

```
python3 -c "import sys;bof='a'*16;bof2='a'*8;sys.stdout.buffer.write(bof.encode('ascii')+b'\xef\xbe\xad\xde'+bof2.encode('ascii')+b'\x21\x52\x54\x55\x55\x35')" | nc example.com 1337
```

But when I execute it my terminal prints out the program's output and as if it is awaiting input, but when I input my text and press enter nothing happens - it still awaits input. I've tried Ctrl+D to end it, I tried `'`, '"', ')'. It didn't work. Any clue why? Ctrl+C ends the execution but I think nothing is sent or at least the output isn't being printed out making it useless for me :(

What I've also tried:
Piping to xxd to check whether there's a mistake there, but nope it seems ok.

I tried googling but apparently to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured it out:

As you can also see in xxd and other similar programs you're missing a newline! Just add a `\n` before you close the byte string literal (`'`) and you're good to go!

Case closed!